# Closed formula for a $gcd$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Le $k≥1$ be  positive integer. I am asking if it is possibe to find a **closed formula** for
$$gcd(2^{2k+5}-3×2^{k+2}+1,2×(2^{k+2}-1)(2^{k+1}-1),2×(3×2^{k+1}-1)(2^{k+2}-1))$$
where $gcd$ is the greatest common divisor.

For $k=1$, we have

$$gcd(2²⁺⁵-3×2¹⁺²+1,2×(2¹⁺²-1)(2¹⁺¹-1),2×(3×2¹⁺¹-1)(2¹⁺²-1))= 7$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Look at the value of the gcd for the first few values of $\ k\ .$ That suggests the following factorisation:
\begin{align}
2^{2k+5}-3\cdot2^{k+2}+1&=2^{2k+5}-2^{k+3}-2^{k+2}+1\\
&=\big(\color{red}{2^{k+2}-1}\big)\big(2^{k+3}-1\big)
\end{align}
of the first number, and you already have
$$
2\big(\color{red}{2^{k+2}-1}\big)\big(2^{k+1}-1\big)
$$
and
$$
2\big(3\cdot2^{k+1}-1\big)\big(\color{red}{2^{k+2}-1}\big)
$$
for the other two numbers. The second of these minus $\ 3\ $ times the first is
$$
4\big(2^{k+2}-1\big)\ .
$$